# Given a function $f(x)$ that is define by $f(x-1)$, by knowing $f(0)$ is it possible to rewrite $f(x)$ without using $f(x-1)$

Tags: functions, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Let a function $f(x)$ that is written using the function itself. Something like Fibonacci sequence $f(x)=f(x-2)+f(x-1)$. Now given enough result of $f(x)$ (in the example of Fibonacci sequence, $f(1)$ and $f(2)$), is it possible to rewrite the function so that it doesn’t require calling itself again, but only uses the input $x$ and the pre-given results (again for Fibonacci sequence it can be written as $f(x)=\frac{\phi^x-(1-\phi)^x}{\sqrt 5}$? Is it possible to prove that any of these self-calling function could be rewritten?

Comment: It really depends on the type of the recurrence. For linear ones, see, e.g., https://brilliant.org/wiki/linear-recurrence-relations/

Comment: Your closed formula for Fibonacci is somewhat wrong though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by saying that expressions such as recursive definition of the Fibonacci sequence you mentioned are usually called [recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation). From what I gathered, you ask the question of whether or not such recurrence relations always admit [closed form solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression). Indeed this is not the case as explained e.g. [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/27598/recurrence-relations-that-do-not-have-a-closed-form-solution), however for large classes of recurrence relations it can be shown that closed form solutions exist. One particular such class is [linear recurrence relations with constant coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant-recursive_sequence) like the Fibonacci recurrence where one can use linear algebra to obtain a closed form solution by defining a linear function $T$ which given some vector consisting of $k$ values of the sequence described by the recurrence and some initial values (which is what you call $f(0)$) produces another such vector containing elements of the aforementioned sequence further along the index. One can then find a formula for the $n$th sequence element by repeatedly applying $T$ to the initial values, which really boils down to multiplying a matrix $A_T$ representing $T$ to the vector of initial values a bunch. A closed form solution for the powers of $A_T$ needed for this can be obtained using Eigendecompositions.